# Elixir: Not able to compile the ExActor dependency

Tags: elixir, actor, elixir-mix

I am trying to run a calculator demo from [ExActor Demos](https://github.com/sasa1977/exactor_demos). It requires adding the new ExActor module as a dependency in the `mix.exs` file as following.

```
defp deps do
 [
   {:exactor, "~> 2.2.3", warn_missing: false}
 ]
end
```

I did `mix deps.get` and `mix deps.update --all` to download the dependency. However, when the I ran the project using `mix run -e CalculatorDemo.exs` , it throws the following error.

```
mycom@MACHINE:~/calculator$ mix run -e CalculatorDemo.run
Compiling 2 files (.ex)

== Compilation error in file lib/calculator.ex ==
** (CompileError) lib/calculator.ex:2: module ExActor is not loaded and could not be found
(elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.use/1
lib/calculator.ex:2: Calculator (module)
```

I am new to Elixir and couldn't find any helpful sources to resolve the above. Any comments on what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `ExActor` module in the `exactor` package. [Since version 0.3.0](https://github.com/sasa1977/exactor/blob/ee4397b22c927d5d70b1b6995fcc1f5afb0f6f28/CHANGELOG.md#v030), you need to `use ExActor.GenServer` to create a GenServer module. The example you linked to was last updated 4 years ago which most likely was before v0.3.0.

So, change:

```
use ExActor
```

to:

```
use ExActor.GenServer
```

The same Calculator example [is also present in the project's README](https://hexdocs.pm/exactor/readme.html#basic-usage) which works with the latest ExActor; you might want to run that code instead.